# How to prepend header before calling sendfile using TCP_NOPUSH in FreeBSD

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, freebsd

I know technically TCP_NOPUSH in FreeBSD and TCP_CORK in Linux suppose to be similar.

In Linux, I can set TCP_CORK, send a header, sendfile() and unset TCP_CORK to insert header in front of the file. In FreeBSD I tried to do the same thing with TCP_NOPUSH but seems like the header is separated from the file content. I must be too dumb to get something wrong.

Here's my code (Linux and BSD):

[shared]:

```
int yes = 1;
int no = 0;
char buf[30] = "Hello World!\n";
```

[Linux]

```
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &yes, sizeof(int)); 
write(sockfd, buf, 30);
sendfile(sockfd, filefd, NULL, SIZE_OF_FILE);
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &no, sizeof(int));
```

result:
Hello World!\n
text....text.....

However in FreeBSD:

```
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NOPUSH, &yes, sizeof(int));
write(sockfd, buf, 30);
sendfile(filefd, sockfd, 0, SIZE_OF_FILE, NULL, NULL, 0);
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NOPUSH, &new, sizeof(int));
```

Result:
Hello World!\n

What should I do in order to get the same behavior as in Linux???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that; differently from Linux, FreeBSD sendfile(2) supports sending headers.